# Difference between GWT and GWTP

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwtp

I am completely new to GWT and so does GWTP.
One of my friends said GWTP is better and easy than GWT.
I tried to study both of them, but still can't figure out what are the main differences and which one is better to use?

Thanks ....

Answer (score 5):

It's not a question of which, but rather A or A + B.  GWTP is a MVP framework built on top of GWT.  It's analogous to ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.

If you're new to GWT, GWTP is probably worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sir ... But i was just wondering that there is no harm using GWTP over GWT .. right? if i am not wrong by A you mean GWT and A+B you mean GWTP ... am i right?

Comment: @VändänÄPatel, that's correct.  You can use just GWT, or both GWT and GWTP.  Using some framework is probably a good idea, especially if you're new to GWT.

Comment: Just a precision: GWTP uses the MVP pattern (and not MVC)

Answer (score 3):

GWTP is **not** a replacement for GWT.

Instead, GWTP is a MVP (Model-View-Presenter) framework aimed to facilitate GWT application development.

GWT apps can be built without GWTP, but, in my experience (working on 10+ GWTP projects), GWTP greatly accelerates your development.